# Pandas / Python = Function that replaces NaN value in column X by matching Column Y with another row that has a value in X

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a function that solves the below problem. I tried solving it by mapping dataframes but this seems like a much better solution, I just can't get the syntax right.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Parent 1 |
| NaN | Parent 1 |
| NaN | Parent 1 |

I want to say "if row[X] is np.NaN, then take the value in Y, see if there are matches and return the value in X from another row if it does, otherwise just take the Y value so that:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Parent 1 |
| Company 1 | Parent 1 |
| Company 1 | Parent 1 |

EDIT: Just clarifying that my dataframe is more like this, so using the ffill/bfill doesn't seem to work (unless I can put a condition into this line).

The data looks more like this

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Parent 1 |
| NaN | Parent 2 |
| NaN | Parent 3 |
| Company 2 | Parent 2 |
| Company 3 | Parent 3 |
| NaN | Parent 1 |

Comment: my guess is you are looking for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-bfill/

Comment: `df['X'] = df.groupby('Y')['X'].ffill().bfill()` . . . assuming that `parent 1` cannot have multiple matches: `company 1` and `company 2`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I've not explained the problem very well. There is other data in the tables too so using the fill method results in the names being erroneously applied to NaN values that I want to keep as NaN because there isn't a match in X.

Comment: Essentially, I want to fill X values but only for matching Y values such that if there is an X value for the same Y value on a different row, I want it to fill, but if there isn't I want the X value to equal the Y. E.g. Parent 4 has no X, so the X value should be Parent 4

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I managed to find a solution to this problem using lambda.

```
#Specify which entries in the Name column are NaN
missing_name = df.X.isnull()

#Set index of new dataframe to Borrower
df_name = df_X.set_index('Y')

#impute the Name from the new dataframe at the null positions in the old dataframe
df.loc[miss_name, 'X'] = df.loc[miss_name, 'Y'].apply(lambda x: df_name.X[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df
            X          Y
0   Company 1   Parent 1
1   NaN         Parent 2
2   NaN         Parent 3
3   Company 2   Parent 2
4   Company 3   Parent 3
5   NaN         Parent 1
```

Firstly, you can create map of `Y` to `X`. So, you can drop `NaN`s from the table and convert to dictionary.

```
temp = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
temp
            X          Y
0   Company 1   Parent 1
3   Company 2   Parent 2
4   Company 3   Parent 3

map1 = pd.Series(temp['X'].values, index=temp['Y']).to_dict()
map1
{'Parent 1': 'Company 1', 'Parent 2': 'Company 2', 'Parent 3': 'Company 3'}
```

Then, you can `fillna` with the map of `Y`. It'll only affect the values where it is NaNs.

```
df['X'] = df['X'].fillna(df['Y'].map(map1))
df

            X          Y
0   Company 1   Parent 1
1   Company 2   Parent 2
2   Company 3   Parent 3
3   Company 2   Parent 2
4   Company 3   Parent 3
5   Company 1   Parent 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` with `first`:

```
df['X'] = df.groupby('Y')['X'].transform('first')
df
```

Output:

```
           X         Y
0  Company 1  Parent 1
1  Company 2  Parent 2
2  Company 3  Parent 3
3  Company 2  Parent 2
4  Company 3  Parent 3
5  Company 1  Parent 1
```